# Wrong draw time in the Hierarchy Viewer?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am doing some tests with the Hierarchy Viewer tool that comes with the Android SDK.

The `Activity` that I am testing has the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/slow_measure"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Slow Measure"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/slow_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Slow Layout"
        android:layout_above="@id/slow_measure"/>

    <com.test.SlowDrawView android:id="@+id/slow_draw"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="Slow Draw"
        android:layout_above="@id/slow_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `SlowDrawView` extends `TextView` but I modified the `onDraw()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

When I check the draw time of this `View` in the hv I notice is less than 3segs, which doesn't make any sense.

Any ideas of why this is happening?
I also noticed that in the android [git repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/master;hb=refs/heads/master) there are two versions of hv. Anyone knows the difference?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Hierarchy Viewer uses "Thread time" instead of "Wall clock time" in its measurements. It means that it doesn't count all the time that thread is waiting some results from another thread (blocking on it) or the thread sleeping time as in your example.

I checked it in Android CPU Monitor and it confirms my idea.

You can load the main thread with some heavy operation to see how that the thread time increases. I did it calling a recursive Fibonacci algorithm for number 39 from `onDraw()` and `onLayout()`:

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  fib(39);
}

public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]