# How does android Hierarchy Viewer measures Draw time?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

The question is about origin of results presented by android [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer). Not what `Draw` time means but how does the tool extract this time from the system. I need to understand whether absolute time makes sense or it is fair only for relative comparison with other views on a screen. [Some experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513716/wrong-draw-time-in-the-hierarchy-viewer) say that it is not straightforward.

Comment: This answer from a previous post may be able to help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842709/measure-layout-and-draw-times-in-hierarchyviewer